# Convert an output of linear model to an json file in R

Tags: r, json, linear-regression

Hi i am trying to convert the coefficients of a linear model into an json file.I have converted to an ject first and then convert it to a json file.I have multiple factors but only one factor output is able to write to the json file.Any leads will be helpful.

```
mod
fs<-summary(mod)
df<-fs$coefficients
my_json<-jsonlite::toJSON(df,force=TRUE,pretty=TRUE)
#print(my_json)
write(my_json,"exportnew.JSON")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species + Sepal.Width, data = iris) %>%
  coefficients() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  write_json("model_coeffs.json", pretty = TRUE)
```

Resulting in file `model_coeffs.json` with content:

```
[
  {
    "name": "(Intercept)",
    "value": 2.2514
  },
  {
    "name": "Speciesversicolor",
    "value": 1.4587
  },
  {
    "name": "Speciesvirginica",
    "value": 1.9468
  },
  {
    "name": "Sepal.Width",
    "value": 0.8036
  }
]
```

You can nest specific variables e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

factor <- mpg %>% colnames() %>% paste0(collapse = "|")

lm(displ ~ manufacturer + class + year, data = mpg) %>%
  coefficients() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(factor = name %>% str_extract(factor)) %>%
  nest(-factor) %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map(~ as.numeric(.$value))) %>%
  write_json("model_coeffs.json", pretty = TRUE)
```

resulting in

```
[
  {
    "data": [-50.2851]
  },
  {
    "factor": "manufacturer",
    "data": [1.246, 1.2091, 1.1909, -1.1599, -0.3859, 0.7445, 0.5315, 1.6728, 0.6315, 0.2552, 1.276, -0.7175, -0.0727, -0.3671]
  },
  {
    "factor": "class",
    "data": [-2.3777, -2.1805, -2.6961, -1.4081, -2.0045, -1.1207]
  },
  {
    "factor": "year",
    "data": [0.0275]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @danloo thanks for ur comment but i have many factors and everything is stored in mod so how do i do for that multiple factors..to make it clear i have attached output of my json object i.e my_json in my code...

Comment: [
  [756.6027, 4.7862, 158.0806, 0],
  [0.0084, 0.0091, 0.9197, 0.3579],
  [0.0368, 0.5785, 0.0636, 0.9493],
  [0.0014, 0.4576, 0.003, 0.9976],
  [0.0942, 1.5013, 0.0627, 0.95],
  [-0.435, 0.1142, -3.8088, 0.0001]
] 
[
  [1862.6582, 3.3174, 561.4827, 0],
  [-0.0037, 0.0063, -0.5844, 0.559],
  [-20.7409, 0.4009, -51.7296, 5.7589e-318],
  [1.9115, 0.3171, 6.027, 2.1714e-09],
  [3.6641, 1.0406, 3.5212, 0.0004],
  [-2.1071, 0.0792, -26.6201, 5.377e-125]
]

Comment: Why does not your output contain any coeff names? My code will save every level of every coeff factor. What is the formula argument of `mod`?

Comment: ya i am also not sure why it doesnt output any coefficient name..fit<-lapply(1:length(red),function(i){
    frml<-as.formula(paste(red[i],"~",pod,sep=""))   ##model formula
    if(!all(pob[,red[i]]%%1==0)){        ##to check if the data is integer or not
      mdl<-lm(frml, data = pob)       ##linear model
      mdl$coefficients[is.na(mdl$coefficients)]<-0
      
    }else{
      mdl<-glm.nb(frml, data = pob)  ##binomial model for integer data
      mdl$coefficients[is.na(mdl$coefficients)]<-0
    }
    mdl

Comment: Do you have 12 predictor factors and each of them have 4 different levels?

Comment: yes ur ryt  @danloo

Comment: @mmmaaraaa Ive added an example on how to do the nesting

Comment: Hi @danloo its producing only one row output in one factor..

Comment: this is because of the `nest`. Its needed so that levels are gouped by thier factors in the json

Comment: Add `mutate(data = data %>% map(~ as.numeric(.$value)))` after nest to wrap ll levels from a factor into one json array

Comment: ya tried  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors this is the error now

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am still getting the error..let me check..thanks